# jetty server run php code

Tags: php, jetty

I want to configure so that jetty runs PHP files, but have been unsuccessful so far. I have Jetty WTP tools installed in my Eclipse IDE.

When I start up the Jetty server. I got the exception: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException org.mortbay.servlet.CGI: org.mortbay.servlet.CGI** and **javax.servlet.UnavailableException: org.mortbay.servlet.CGI**. I put a simple php file(index.php) under my WebContent folder. I also downloaded this [library](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/JKL/Downloadorgmortbayjettyjar.htm) and added it to the classpath(Eclipse: build path and add external jar). I have no clue now what I've done wrong. I also compiled php with:

```
./configure --with-fastcgi=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

And my web.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Sample PHP Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PHP</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.mortbay.servlet.CGI</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>commandPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>/usr/local/bin/php-cgi-fix</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PHP</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.php/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.php</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

It could be my php-cgi-fix file, I got the followig text i terminal when i open it:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/php-cgi-fix ; exit;
/usr/local/bin/php-cgi-fix: line 3: /usr/bin/php-cgi: No such file or directory
logout
```

Shouldn't be /usr/local/php-cgi instead? Ok I tried that now, but still I got the same ecxeptions when I launch the server.

(I really don't like to use maven too!)

Answer (score 2):

You almost certainly **don't** want to follow those instructions - they're for Jetty 5 which is *very* old.

Try following one of these 2 sets of instructions

- http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/01/04/running-quercus-in-jetty-web-server/
- http://www.owengriffin.com/posts/2010/04/22/Writing_PHP_applications_with_Maven_and_Jetty.html

They take very different approaches, so you'll need to decide which way you want to do.

The first one uses Quercus which is an implementation of PHP written in Java.
The second one uses CGI to run the standard PHP implementation.

Report back with any specific issues you have.

Comment: Sorry for late response. I have been trying to figure out how to do this all yesterday. I wont try the first link, but I tried the second link, which is strikingly similar to my link. Well I got the error service unavailable?

Comment: Sorry but those links are not for me. I dont use maven either:(

Answer (score 2):

Here's what i did to get it running:

Im using jetty-distribution-8.1.5.v20120716

- extract jetty-distribution-8.1.5.v20120716.zip to let's say a directory Jetty
- i don't think this is necessary, but i didn't want other webapps/servlets to interfere the configuration, so: empty the directories Jetty/contexts, Jetty/contexts-available, Jetty/webapps
- optional: to get debugging messages add the following in Jetty/etc/jetty.xml

```
    <Get class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log" name="log">
      <Call name="setDebugEnabled">
        <Arg type="boolean">true</Arg>
      </Call>
    </Get>
```

- create a file Jetty/bin/php5-cgi-fix.sh with the content

```
    #!/usr/bin/bash
    export SCRIPT_FILENAME=$1
    /usr/bin/php5-cgi
```

- create the following directories: Jetty/webapps/MYPROJECT, Jetty/webapps/MYPROJECT/WEB-INF, Jetty/webapps/MYPROJECT/cgi-bin

  the content of Jetty/webapps/MYPROJECT/WEB-INFO/web.xml is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <web-app
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
      version="2.4"
    >

     <display-name>MYPROJECT</display-name>

     <servlet>
       <servlet-name>PHP</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CGI</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

       <init-param>
            <param-name>commandPrefix</param-name>
            <param-value>../../../bin/php5-cgi-fix.sh</param-value>
       </init-param>

          <init-param>
              <param-name>Path</param-name>
              <param-value>/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin</param-value>
          </init-param>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>cgibinResourceBase</param-name>
              <param-value>webapps/MYPROJECT</param-value>
          </init-param>

    <!--
          <init-param>
              <param-name>cgibinResourceBaseIsRelative</param-name>
              <param-value>true</param-value>
          </init-param>
    -->
    <!--
       <init-param>
            <param-name>ENV_yourRequiredEnvironmentVariable</param-name>
            <param-value>yourValue</param-value>
       </init-param>
    -->
       <!-- Path, other ENV_variables including ENV_SystemRoot, ENV_REDIRECT_STATUS on Windows -->
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>PHP</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.php</url-pattern>
       <!-- Any other URL patterns that are needed by your app to be processed by PHP -->
     </servlet-mapping>

     <!-- If you want http://yourhost/yourapp to call yourapp/yourapp.php then make a welcome file -->
    <!--
     <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.php</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>
    -->
    </web-app>
```

- create a php file like Jetty/webapps/MYPROJECT/cgi-bin/test.php with content

  <?php phpinfo();
- in php.ini set
  cgi.force_redirect = 0
- run jetty:

  java -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CGI.LEVEL=DEBUG -jar start.jar etc/jetty-requestlog.xml

  OR

  java -jar start.jar
- test with

  ```
  http://localhost:8080/MYPROJECT/cgi-bin/test.php
  ```

HINTS:

- in case you try to use this on windows via e.g. php5-cgi-fix.bat file you have to change the command prefix in web.xml config like this:

  cmd.exe /c ../../../bin/php5-cgi-fix.bat
- jetty source can be obtained from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/aggregate/jetty-all/
  where org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/CGI.java is the cgi servlets code which executes the php scripts

hth

Comment: For Jetty 9.0.x, I had to add <async-supported>true</async-supported> to the web.xml file, between <servlet-class> and <load-on-startup>. I also had to add the line "--module=servlets" in start.ini, so that org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CGI, and its dependencies, would be available in the classpath.

Comment: I am getting `500: Failed to exec CGI` in jetty, using windows 7 and my **php5-cgi-fix.bat** would look like `SET SCRIPT_FILENAME=%1
C:\php\php-cgi.exe`, the command prompt tells `PHP Warning:  Unknown: Filename cannot be empty in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 1):

The servlet class has been renamed to `org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CGI`